# Word as editor in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, ribbon

Word is the default editor for Outklook messages.

How can I make the Word ribbons (which may include custom functions) visible when editing a message?

Comment: I don't think Outlook pulls in any customizations made in Word.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the editing tools are available on the `Format Text` ribbon. You can *right* click on the tab and customize the ribbon to add or remove features. I am not sure you will be able to have all the features of Word.

[image]